# Detect Java location from Makefile

Tags: java, makefile, java-native-interface

I have a makefile, which needs to know the location of the Java include directory because it makes use of the jni.h file.  What is the best way of allowing the Makefile to auto-detect where Java is installed on Linux?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I think I've decided to just have the user set the JAVA_HOME variable before they run the makefile.

Answer (score 8):

How about using

```
JAVA_HOME=$(shell readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")
```

Adapted from:
https://serverfault.com/questions/143786/how-to-determine-java-home-on-debian-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

You can try this too:

```
JAVA_HOME:=$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(new java.io.File(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home")).getParent());')
```

Answer (score 1):

The JAVA_HOME environment variable contains the path to the Java installation.

Comment: I did think of that, but on my test box, the JAVA_HOME variable is not set (which was how it was by default after a clean install).

Comment: I've actually never seen a java installation without the JAVA_HOME variable set.  Did Java come with your distribution, yet they unset the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: Yeah, it came with the distribution (Mint linux), but when I try "echo $JAVA_HOME", it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use the `which` command, such as `which java`. It should tell you where the location of the java exec it would use is.

However, I'd recommend setting up JAVA_HOME as Erick pointed out.

Comment: The result will probably be `/etc/alternatives/java`, which is not very helpful

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that command.  This tells me where the "java" executable is, but this is just a link to the real location, which should be something like (/usr/lib/jvm/java-version-here/bin).  It's this folder that I need to find the location of.

Comment: The result you get isn't a link - it's a string you can parse that and get the folder from it, no?

Comment: Also, I still recommend setting the JAVA_HOME, as this is the more common convention amongst Java-based programs and scripts. Although, it's worth noting that more Java is built with `ant` than with `make`.

Comment: Oh, ok I see.  Yeah, when I do an "ls -la" on the "/usr/bin" directory I see the line "javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javac".  I think this would work, but how would I get that string inside of a Makefile, and then parse it so that I only had the string "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22"?